# How can I combine rows of data when their character values are equal? (R)

Tags: r, merge

I have a dataset that was recorded by observation(each observation has its own row of data). I am looking to combine/condense these rows by the plant they were found on - currently a character variable. All other columns are numerical vales.

EX:

This is the raw data
|Sci_Name|Honeybee_count|Other_bee_Obsevrved|Stem_count|
|---|---|---|---|
|Zizia aurea|1|5|10|
|Asclepias viridiflora|15|1|3|
|Viola unknown|0|0|4|
|Zizia aurea|0|2|6|
|Zizia aurea|3|6|3|
|Asclepias viridiflora|8|2|17|

and I want:

| Sci_Name | Honeybee_count | Other_bee_Obsevrved | Stem_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zizia aurea | 4 | 13 | 19 |
| Asclepias viridiflora | 23 | 3 | 20 |
| Viola unknown | 0 | 0 | 4 |

I am currently pulling this data from a CSV already in table form. I have been attempting to create a new table/data frame with one entry of each plant species, and blanks/0s for each other variable, which I can then use to c-binding the two together. This, however, has been clunky at best and I am having trouble figuring out how to have each row check itself. I am open to any approach, let me know what you think!

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the formula method in `aggregate` from `base R`.  On the rhs of the `~`, specify the grouping variable and on the lhs, use `.` for denoting the rest of the variables.  Specify the `FUN` as `sum` and it will do the column wise sum by group

```
aggregate(. ~ Sci_Name, df1, sum)
```

-output

```
            Sci_Name Honeybee_count Other_bee_Obsevrved Stem_count
1 Asclepias viridiflora             23                   3         20
2         Viola unknown              0                   0          4
3           Zizia aurea              4                  13         19
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sci_Name = c("Zizia aurea", "Asclepias viridiflora", 
"Viola unknown", "Zizia aurea", "Zizia aurea", "Asclepias viridiflora"
), Honeybee_count = c(1L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 8L), Other_bee_Obsevrved = c(5L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 2L), Stem_count = c(10L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 17L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```